# How to exclude cells in a column from sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataset below, I want to calculte the aggregated sum of "notes" of each school, except the school "B", where I want to be equal zero or missing

```
 student school  notes   nbr_of_student_per_school
    1         A      12                     45
    1         A      13                     45
    2         A      10                     45
    3         B      13                     -
    4         C      16                     46
    5         A      10                     45
    6         C      20                     46
    7         C      10                     46
    8         B      11                     -

df.groupby(['Country'])['notes'].sum()
```

Comment: Would doing a temporary dataframe where school B is equal to 0 and then doing the groupby but on that temporary dataframe be a solution ?

Comment: my database is larger than that, and requires daily updates, so changing in a single database is better than doing two databases. thank you

Comment: Okay, therefore this would do the trick : `df.loc[df['school'] != 'B',:].groupby(['Country'])['notes'].sum()`

Comment: It generates a new dataframe with A, C and D and the sum, how can I do, if I want to put the result in the same dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.query('school != "B"').groupby('school')['notes'].sum()
```

So you are only selecting the subset of the dataframe where the school is not B

---

**EDIT:**

Another approach re: comments:

```
# calculate mean
df['new_col'] = df.groupby('school')['notes'].transform('sum')

# now set B school sum to np.nan
df.loc[df['school'] == 'B', 'new_col'] = np.nan
```

Comment: It generates a new dataframe with A, C and D and the sum, how can I do, if I want to put the result in the same dataset

Comment: Try: `df['new_col'] = df.query('school != "B"').groupby('school')['notes'].transform('sum')`

Comment: I got this exception : Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Comment: It works for me, with the data that you provided. but see my edit for another approach.